# how can I justify only my input tags in a column?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have html code like this

```
<div>
    <img class="img-class1" src="" />
    <img class="img-class2" src="" />
    <input class="input-class" />
</div>
<div>
    <img class="img-class1" src="" />
    <input class="input-class" />
</div>
<div>
    <input class="input-class" />
</div>
```

I need to see inputs in a column. I have hundreds of these in my program. I wan to know How can I arrange it by css or jquery.
Thank

Comment: What do you mean? You want to see them next to each other?

Comment: No, I want it appears like I put them on the table like this:
<table>
    <tr></tr>
</table>

Comment: No, I want it appears like I put them on the table like this:
<table>
    <tr><td>img</td><td>img</td><td>input</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>img</td><td>input</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td>input</td></tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

In CSS,

```
div{
    display:table-cell;  /* Divs will be displayed as if cells in a table */
}
```

You probably want to give the divs a class and use that class instead, of course.

If you want to make them fill the div width more nicely, add `width: 1%;` into this.